# no view found for id viewpager fragment android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, illegalargumentexception, tabbed

I have 3 fragment, first `mainFragment`, `tab1Fragment`, and `Detaitab1Fragment`.
I want to call a *Detaitab1Fragment* in my *tab1Fragment*.

This is code when i call my Detaitab1Fragment in tab1Fragment

```
 BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
 transaction.commit();
```

and this code my `SectionPageAdapter` on mainFragment

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    NotifikasiFragment.SectionPageAdapter adapter = new NotifikasiFragment.SectionPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new TabKelasNotifikasiFragment(),"Kelas");
    adapter.addFragment(new TabSekolahNotifikasiFragment(),"Sekolah");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
public class SectionPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mfragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();



    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mfragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public SectionPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mfragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mfragmentList.size();
    }

}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}
```

and this is code when i call viewPager on mainFragment

```
SectionPageAdapter sectionPageAdapter = new SectionPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.containerNotifikasi);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabsNotifikasi);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

this code on below is my mainFragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.fania.suara_project.fragment.notifikasi.NotifikasiFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="NOTIFIKASI"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></TextView>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabsNotifikasi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/containerNotifikasi"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and code tab1Fragment.xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.fania.suara_project.fragment.notifikasi.TabKelasNotifikasiFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:background="@color/kuning"
    android:id="@+id/recycleViewKelasNotifikasi"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

My FrameLayout is in content_drawable.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.fania.suara_project.activity.DrawableActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_drawable">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and i call content_drawable on Drawableactivity.class

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

R.id.drawable_layout is include content_drawable.xml

but i found error like this

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0099 (com.example.fania.suara_project:id/frame) for fragment BlankFragment{9df0d4d #0 id=0x7f0e0099}
```

anyone can help me ? 
Thank's

Comment: what's your FrameLayout's id in xml?

Comment: @VishalVaishnav  I've edited my question with file .xml

Comment: where is frame in your xml...which will be framelayout?

Comment: @VishalVaishnav my framelayout is on content_drawable.xml .. I've edited my question with file .xml

Comment: where are you define content_drawable.xml in your java code?

Comment: @VishalVaishnav I've edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, your fragments are in the same activity, right? Try call `getActivity().getFragmentManager()` (or `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`) instead `getChildFragmentManager()`. 
Your container with id="frame" is in your activity's xml?

Comment: yes ,that's right...
but which fragment when i call getActivity().getFragmentManager() (or getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() ??

Comment: You can do this in any fragment. This call simply refers to the FragmentManager in the activity in which this fragment was added.

Comment: Glad to help you :)